# How to add a link to open a file without a Win10 security warning in iTextSharp v5

Tags: windows, security, itext

When creating a new PDF file using iTextSharp I am able to create a link in the document using the .SetAnchor method that navigates to the specified URL when clicked, such as

```
anchor.SetAnchor(...some URL...);
```

However, all I really want the click to do is open or execute a specified file on my local Win10 machine, and this also works if I merely specify the file instead of a URL, such as

```
anchor.SetAnchor("notepad.exe");
```

The issue is that I must use iTextSharp to create many of versions of the PDF file, with each version having a different file name itself as well as a different name for the file the link opens.  Although I have no problem getting this to work, the annoyance is that whenever I click the link in a new version I get a "Security Warning" popup from Windows wanting to know if the "connection" should be allowed.

Because the warning mentions a "connection" I get the feeling there may be a method something like SetAnchor that will produce a link specifically intended for opening files rather than URLs and that will not result in a Security Warning each time the name of the file the link represents is changed.  If so, what is it?  If not, is there some other reasonable approach to avoid the security warning?  This is all being used on my local machine so I know there are no security issues with the PDFs or the files being opened.

Comment: This is purely a Windows 10 security feature. It has nothing to do with PDF or iText. You see, for a PDF, there is no "magical" difference between a local file and an URL, it's just a location that it passes on to the operating system. I suggest that you ask on the Super User Stack Exchange how you turn off that security feature: https://superuser.com/. All caveats apply of course, that this will turn your computer into a shooting gallery for malware...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer for both iTextSharp and iText7 as shown below.  I suspect the iText7 version could be simplified if I actually knew more about it, but I currently only use iTextSharp and don't really know much about it either.  Both versions open the file with no interference from Windows 10 security:

iTextSharp:

```
     Paragraph p = new Paragraph(
       new Chunk("Click to open")
       .SetAction(
         new PdfAction("C:/temp/Doc1.pdf", "")
         )
     );
     document.Add(p);
```

iText7:

```
     PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(writer);
     Document document = new Document(pdfDoc);
     document.SetFontProvider(new BasicFontProvider());

     PdfFont font = PdfFontFactory.CreateFont();
     PdfFileSpec spec = PdfFileSpec.CreateExternalFileSpec(pdfDoc, "C:/temp/Doc1.pdf");
     PdfAction action = PdfAction.CreateLaunch(spec);
     Paragraph p = new Paragraph(new Link("Click to open", action));
     document.Add(p);
```